# Why is the result of system() in Perl not the exact exit code of my script?

Tags: perl

I have the following perl script (`test.pl`):

```
my $exit_code = system('./test.py');
print $exit_code."\n";
```

that is trying to capture the exit code from a python executable (`test.py`):

```
#!/bin/env python
import sys
sys.exit(2)
```

Directly running python executable returns 2, which is what I expected:

```
> ./test.py
> echo $?
2
```

However, running perl returns something different:

```
> perl test.pl
512
```

Why did perl capture a different exit code from python?

Comment: `512` *can't* be an exit code -- exit codes are single-byte, making the value too large to fit.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: Perl's `system()` returns a rather funky version of an exit code. To get the actual value, you need to shift right by 8. So 512 is a valid return value which actually means 2 :-/

Comment: @DaveCross, yes, the answer specifying that already existed; my point was that what perl was capturing is clearly not a literal exit code at all.

Comment: @Charles Duffy, They are 16-bit in Windows

Comment: @ikegami, ...if the OP hadn't been using shebangs on their scripts, I might have considered Windows a plausible platform, but as the situation is...

Comment: @Charles Duffy, I never said the OP was using Windows. Your comment wasn't even about the OP (since he used `exit(2)`, not `exit(512)`). I just pointed out an error in your claim.

Comment: The context (of a UNIX platform) was present in the question to which the comment was applied. If I make a claim about `printf` on a question talking about C, it's very different from a claim about `printf` on a question talking about shell. I keep myself outside of win32-specific contexts for the most part, and when outside them have no intent of saying "except on Windows" every time I open my mouth.

Comment: Re "*The context (of a UNIX platform) was present in the question to which the comment was applied*", No, it wasn't. There's nothing unix-specific about the question. Executing the exact same program on Windows will give you exactly the same result. A reader would have no reason to believe the comment is unix-specific, and would thus be misinformed by your incorrect comment. You failed to take Win32 out of the context as you claim you do. If you had, I would not have needed to comment.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The child might not even have gotten to call `exit`. As such, `system`'s returns value (aka `$?`) packs more information than just the `exit` parameter.

```
if    ( $? == -1  ) { die "Can't launch child: $!\n"; }
elsif ( $? & 0x7F ) { die "Child killed by signal ".( $? & 0x7F )."\n"; }
elsif ( $? >> 8   ) { die "Child exited with error ".( $? >> 8 )."\n"; }
else                { print "Child executed successfully\n"; }
```

This is [documented](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html).

Answer (score 5):

[The documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html) says *"To get the actual exit value, shift right by eight"*.